# JS cookies refresh itself when the page refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I need  to use cookies for my new webshop, so if the page refreshes the old values will stay in.
Now i've created my cookies, and it works perfectly fine, but when I'm refreshing the page, the cookie goes empty again. If i'm going to a different page, the cookie stays (path:/)

Now i'm confused and need someone to clarify what i'm doing wrong right here, so I came here to ask my question!

Here is the code im using

```
$.cookie.raw = true;
$.cookie.json = true;
$.cookie('cart', unescape);


function UpdateTotals() {

                TotalPrice = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < Orders.length ; i++) {
                    var SearchResult = SubMenuItems.filter(function(v) {
                        return v.submenu_id === Orders[i];
                    })[0];
                    TotalPrice += parseFloat(SearchResult.price);

                $.cookie('cart', JSON.stringify(Orders), { expires: 7, path: '/'  });
```

Now if I click on some orders, the cookies stays filled with the jSon values.

Comment: Sounds like you're running `UpdateTotals()` again with no orders loaded.

Comment: Yeah that's right, but otherwise it won't update my order list in the cookies!

Comment: Why would you want to write the cookie when the orders are empty?  Can you show some more relevant code?

Comment: I actually want to write a cookie when the user orders something. I thought, if I do this in the "updatetotals" then it updates the cookie everytime when the user orders something.

Comment: Yes, that much is clear, but there's no code to show us anything else that is happening.  Like I said, it sounds like you're calling that function when the page loads, so you have no order details and you write the cookie (empty).  Without any other code it's not possible to help.

Comment: Ahh allright, let me update my code! I'm going for a quick break, ill message you!